# Design of Job Scheduler

Tags: quartz-scheduler, scheduler, job-scheduling

I want to know the high level design of Job Scheduler like [Quartz Scheduler](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) . 
Can somebody please point me to it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at this github project [CLICK HERE](https://github.com/alidadasb/TestQuartzOnDemandJob) I used from @alidad. I used this project to customize my quartz needs. Maybe it can help you too.